# Angular2 e2e hangs in devmode

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm e2e testing a angular application. When I use the angular-cli to start the, the e2e test get stuck after text is sent to a input element.

When I run it on a compiled aot version that is served from a nginx server it works.

There are no errors in the logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your app, I'm gonna guess here. I'm guessing your app calls another service/app to process the text input. Unless you have mocked out that service, running e2e from angular directly would not have started external services. That would explain why it works on the fully compiled version

Comment: I solved it by turning off live reload.